# Using mysql on Xshell 7 how to write a code group by month as January, February, March, etc

Tags: mysql

I coded:

```
select date_format(date,'%M') as 'Month', sum(new_cases) as 'Cases',sum(new_deaths) as 'Deaths' 
from covid_county 
group by date_format(date,'%M');

+-----------+----------+--------+
| Month     | Cases    | Deaths |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| April     |  1101441 |  12555 |
| August    |  3003112 |  15657 |
| December  |  1771746 |  11026 |
| February  |  4050275 |  60855 |
| January   | 18939780 |  55275 |
| July      |  3551216 |  10381 |
| June      |  3101954 |  10140 |
| March     |  1039405 |  30932 |
| May       |  2484708 |  10903 |
| November  |  1169068 |  21761 |
| October   |  1017044 |  11455 |
| September |  1736017 |  11529 |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

The outcome sorted in alphabetical order. I need to group by month starting from January to December

I tried using this command:

```
select date_format(date,'%M') as 'Month', sum(new_cases) as 'Cases',sum(new_deaths) as 'Deaths' 
from covid_county 
group by date_format(date,'%m');
```

ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbuser_27.covid_county.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I need my month column to sort from January to December instead of sort by alphabet.

Comment: I tried to upload my table but once posted it didn't look right. However, you can still see that the month was sorted not in chronological order but in alphabetical order.